# jquery ajax request intermittent issue

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hoping someone can help. I've got this code:

```
 $('.FinderOptions').on("click", ".nextButton", function(){
            console.log("Next has been clicked");
             var session = $('#sessionvalue').val();
             var querystring = $("#formStep").serialize() + "&session=" + session;
            $.ajaxSetup({async: false, 
                        cache: false});
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: querystring,
                    url: "includes/finder/processstep.php",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(msg){
.....
```

But there seems to be an intermittant issue that it doesn't submit the ajax request.

I had it working on my local xampp server but when I made it live it some of the time it just wont submit the ajax request. (No errors in firebug when running but it picks up the 'next has been clicked' log..).

I tried Googling it and found these suggestions which I put in the example above:

```
$.ajaxSetup({async: false, 
                            cache: false});
```

But that doesn't seem to sort it either.

It's really strange, but has anyone got any ideas what it could be?

Tried putting an example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/hkrB5/
(which of course works fine :( )

Comment: I've been working on trying to figure it out and when it doesn't work I get an error code of 0.

Comment: Added this in: http://aaronsaray.com/blog/2010/08/24/how-to-handle-ajax-errors-with-jquery/ - When it fails (usually on IE) it says: 
There was an error with the AJAX request.
HTTP Error (0 Error: Access is denied.).

Comment: No one got back to me but I **finally** figured it out.

I have a Base url set without the www but when I visited the page with www. it would submit the request - take the www. out and it would. Force remove the www. and sorted. Hope this helps anyone else in the same situation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one got back to me but I finally figured it out. I have a Base url set without the www but when I visited the page with www. it would submit the request - take the www. out and it would. Force remove the www. and sorted. Hope this helps anyone else in the same situation :)